# Facebook ID from URL

Tags: facebook

Given a facebook url such as http://facebook.com/cnn, is there any way to get the ID of that page short of scraping it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is better (and **legal**) to do this with graph API. Just perform API request to `https://graph.facebook.com/cnn` and get id from the response.

Here is the response for `cnn`:

```
{
   "id": "5550296508",
   "name": "CNN",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs178.ash2/41813_5550296508_728_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/cnn",
   "category": "Company",
   "website": "www.cnn.com\nwww.ireport.com\n",
   "username": "cnn",
   "company_overview": "TRIVIA FROM THE CNN TOUR...",
   "products": "CNN US...",
   "likes": 1689936
}
```

Comment: A very good choice if you're working against user IDs; if it's not guaranteed, there's a more general way to handle URLs via the Graph API. See the answer below.

Comment: Note that if you get an `Unsupported get request`, the page [may be restricted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6843796/241211).

Comment: Still working, but now it needs an access token to read the resource. See more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/?locale=en_US.

Answer (score 6):

Facebook's own Graph API supports it. From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/):

> The "ids" query parameter also accepts URLs. This is useful for
>   finding IDs of URLs in the Open Graph. For example:
>   https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/

Comment: for external urls. this is used for getting the open graph info for a site, not a fb object id for an internal object.

Answer (score 1):

As of Today(28th July 2015), There still exists an easy way to get page(or user's) id.

Browse to facebook page(or user) url. The syntax is *https://www.facebook.com/[username or pagename]*

Right click to view source and then search for string **"pageID":** in case of page. The numeric id next to searched string will be id.
In case of user, search for **"uid":**.

Comment: Yes. Very much legal. We are just picking up this from html source

Answer (score -2):

Been working with it today. So, for people who want to know how this works. Use this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<the_fb-address>?access_token=$accessToken
```

And remember: this is only for pages. Not user pages/friends' timelines etc.
Those will have to approve your Facebook App first before you can read their profiles.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  This would create a URL object.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/url/

Comment: Then you probably did a request on a personal facebook page, not an official page that you have to like. There was no need to downvote this answer. We have this up and running.

Comment: Can you provide a full example?  Here's a post from an official page from CNN, and your method does not appear to work.  `GET /v2.8/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcnn%2Fposts%2F10155873400471509`  (with access token...using the Graph API explorer)  I just get back a "website" object, and nothing about the public post on an official public page.