# Graph API: How do I post to a Page with Age Restriction?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I understand from experimentation and other posts I've found here that if a Page has a specific age restriction, it becomes necessary to use "the end-user's access token" for posting to the Page, as this access token provides the insight necessary to validate the user's age.

The problem I'm having is that my application (a WordPress plugin) uses the access tokens acquired through the **/me/accounts** endpoint, but these access tokens don't work (when a page has age restrictions). I assume these access tokens represent the permissions and profile of the the **/me** used in their acquisition, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I have verified that age restriction is the problem. If I turn off the age restriction on the page, the plugin works perfectly. Turn it back on, and the application fails to post.

How do I remedy this?

Comment: Is it something as stupid as your account isn't old enough to post on the page?

Comment: Thanks Mike and webarto - always helpful to know upfront who the jerks in the forum are...

Comment: Old question, but i just had the same issue and came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843796/graph-api-returns-false-or-unsupported-get-request-accessing-public-facebook