# View Page that is Age Restricted

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

I am creating a Facebook Gallery on our bar's website that pulls our albums from our Facebook Business Page. When I put an age restriction on the Fan page I am unable to view the albums. How can I keep the age restriction and still see the albums on our website. The website has a built in code to verify age before letting them see the site.

```
    $FBid   = '116312615074882'; // Will add a Admin item for this

    //Get the contents of a Facebook page 
    $FBpage = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$FBid.'/albums');
    //Interpret data with JSON
    $photoData = json_decode($FBpage);

    foreach($photoData->data as $data) {

        $images[] = array(
                    'id' => $data->id,
                    'name' => $data->name
                    );
    }

    $this->data->images = $images;
        $this->template
        ->title('Facebook Gallery')
        ->build('index', $this->data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the game, but the high-level answer is you need to use a page_token for that page, or an access_token for a user who is old enough to view the age gated page. See [Graph API returns 'false' or 'Unsupported get request' accessing public Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843796/graph-api-returns-false-or-unsupported-get-request-accessing-public-facebook) for more details.