# Error while trying to get ids form Android's Facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to send app request to other facebook friends with android sdk using WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder like is written on the example page.

But any time I get an Id and later try to get the info of the user I'm getting this error on graph:

```
{
    "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
    }
}
```

this is the sample response to https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=10152368552599473

Answer (score 0):

This error occur due to several problem in permissions of your page

1. go to edit page ->manage permission

   check Age restrictions : 13+
2. go to basic information -> Start Type:: set to launched

Links for your reference :

1. [Unsupported get request in Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739609/unsupported-get-request-in-facebook-graph-api)
2. [Unusual behavior of facebook grap API ("type": "GraphMethodException", "code": 100)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957095/unusual-behavior-of-facebook-grap-api-type-graphmethodexception-code-1)

I am quite sure this will solve your problem.