# What is the error in the following code

Tags: facebook, events, syntax

Here is a function which is call when user click a button to attend a event on  facebook, these following code get the login information from user and add there particular event to the user fb event to attending the event.

These code is giving me the syntax error, i does not Know what is the error. Please help its needy.

```
function gogingtoevent() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.status == 'connected') {
                FB.api('/816891388384961/attending', 
                 function (response) {
                   if (response && !response.error) {
                        alert('Attending');
                       }else{
                            alert (JSON.stringify(response));   
                       }
                    });
            }else{
                alert('Not Responding');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual error message and line number of the error? This code looks syntactically correct (but could be formatted better).

Comment: {"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}

Comment: this is a error which is generated and i read the error code its because of syntax in give the error

Comment: This looks like an issue with the URL you are providing. Are you sure you have permissions set correctly? This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957095/unusual-behavior-of-facebook-grap-api-type-graphmethodexception-code-1

Comment: i set privacy of event is open invite

Comment: RSVP-ing as attending requires a _POST_ request … you are making a GET request only.

Comment: when i add post it give the error

Comment: (#299) Requires extended permission: rsvp_event

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a POST request to this edge, and you need the `rsvp_event` permission.

It's all in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event/attending#publish
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#adding

Comment: how to set rsvp_event permission

Comment: You need to request it during the app login flow. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#adding

Comment: i add the type post and rsvp_event permission scope: 'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,rsvp_event'

Comment: `read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access` are all deprecated. HOw does your code look like now? Without the code nobody will be able to help you. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/

Comment: FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
                FB.api("/816891388384961/attending",
    "POST", 
                 function (response) {
                   if (response && !response.error) {
                     alert('Attending');
                       }else{
       alert (JSON.stringify(response));   
        }
                    });
            }
        },{
   scope: 'rsvp_event'
 });

Comment: {"error":{"message":"(#299) Requires extended permission: rsvp_event","type":"OAuthException","code":299}}

Comment: Then, the permission has either not been granted, or not been requested. Remove the app from the user profile's app settings, and try to login again.