# Facebook API error subcode 33

Tags: facebook, curl

I have an app that gets `leads` from facebook after webhook request when leads fill out forms: Some pages are throwing this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '233332620530416' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "HIItB4mggfk"
    },
    "__debug__": {}
}
```

I cannot find the error subcode description in Facebooks API docs.

Comment: Well then I suggest you take the content of the `message` property as substitute.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52380426/6667442

Answer (score 4):

Visit Business Settings > Users > System Users > Chose «Conversions API System User» > Add Assets. Add your Pixel with ID from your request to the list of assets System User can access.

[image]

Comment: is there some delay after adding assets and before you can successfully call the API?

Answer (score 3):

Check you access token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

Your app might be missing a needed permission scope.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue a few times and the error led me to spend an hour or two combing the docs. The real issue for me each time has been malformed json in the request body (I'm using curl).  Dumb I know, but in case a poor soul comes across this. Be sure to validate your json before you decide you query is wrong.

Comment: is there anything wrong in my case : 
   fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${PSID}?fields=first_name&access_token=${PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`)
        .then(res => res.json()) ? because it feels OK to me and I am still getting the same response... (sorry for formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when adding access_token in post body, worked when adding parameters to url.
Success result using postman

[image]

Not success result using postman

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer recently

Follow this steps using postman

https://graph.facebook.com/page-name/feed

headers:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Body:

```
message: "your message"
link:"your web link "
access_token:'Your access token '
```

Comment: You don't explain anything

Answer (score -1):

Add your access token in the Authorization tab, then choose Oauth2.0 and add your access token on the right side. Please refer to the screenshot for the postman.[Click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj59Q.jpg)