# What does it mean "error_subcode": 33 in the facebook response error?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Does anybody know what does it mean `error_subcode`: 33 in the facebook response error? I know it's related to a mission permission but I want to be 100% sure.

We received the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'XXXX'
does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does
not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"error_subcode":33,"fbtrace_id":"BRwGjA9kkKU"}}
```

But in the Facebook API documentation about Graph API  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/ , I cannot find `error_subcode` with value 33.

I want that I can rely on this subcode to verify that I don't have permissions to get the resource from Facebook API because I don't want to rely on the error message.

Comment: I don't think you can get that. _"does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation"_ - it is deliberately that vague, so that you can not determine the existence or non-existence of an object from it. It's a privacy issue.

Comment: In our case, we receive a message from a user with this ID. When attempting to get their details, we are left with this message. So we know that the user exists, just not why we can't read their info. We can get info on other users, so at least some work. Any ideas how to reproduce this behavior, are there any user settings which might prevent loading the user details?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook API error subcode 33](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856553/facebook-api-error-subcode-33)

Comment: I got same error and I added this permission -> pages_manage_ads to my access_token, my error solved

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Facebook bug portal link to the similar issue:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/316526372199563/

The gist of it is:

> these users registered for Facebook/Messenger using their phone number and such users are not yet queryable by the API. This is on the roadmap for the API, please keep an eye on our changelog for when this goes live in a future version: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog"

Answer (score 3):

I can't offer a definitive solution, as there seem to be multiple possible causes. However, I encountered this today and wish to offer this possible cause.

If you are encountering this error when you are testing your Facebook TEST app, it might be related to the fact that you're in TEST app mode.

In my case, I worked on implementing Facebook login for a while. When my partner joined in development, he couldn't log in in his development environment. He got the error you mention for the 'me' endpoint:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "____"
    }
}
```

This had actually already been deployed and tested to our production environment, **where we are both able to register and log in just fine**.

After I added him as Administrator to the Facebook TEST app, the issue resolved and he could register and log in on his own development environment.

So, you may want to check if this is applicable to you. An easy way to check is to use the keys for the real app in your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Error subcode 33 information as per Facebook official documentation:

Error code 100, subcode 33

Unsupported post request.

This error may occur if your access token is not added as a system user with appropriate permissions to the ad account that owns a Custom Audience. Verify the ad account in Business Manager and verify all system users appear under the ad account as Admin:

Click on Business Settings

Click the ad account

Select Add people

Search for system user and add them as Admins

Retry your API call

Here's the link to the Facebook marketing API error reference.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/error-reference/

This contains the resolution for error 33 along with all the other errors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).