# Can I create a facebook campaign using facebook graph api without any payment

Tags: java

I am using the graph api to create the campaign to node **{ad_account_id}/campaigns**, but it gives me the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '376242159133206' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Hk5bquTFXZj"
  }
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unusual behavior of facebook grap API ("type": "GraphMethodException", "code": 100)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957095/unusual-behavior-of-facebook-grap-api-type-graphmethodexception-code-1)