# Is there a way to determine the root cause for 'Unsupported get request' when accessing a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This stack overflow question illustrates the various reasons why the facebook graph api may limit access to a facebook page: [Graph API returns 'false' or 'Unsupported get request' accessing public Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843796/graph-api-returns-false-or-unsupported-get-request-accessing-public-facebook/6847088#6847088)

However, my question is what are the ways to figure out the exact root restriction cause (graph api, facebook ui, etc.) **when you can access the facebook page with a user access token and not the app access token**. I'm scraping some data from facebook pages and I want to be able to tell the page owners the specific restriction that needs to be adjusted to make the page visible to our app.

These are the restrictions mentioned in the stack overflow thread:

1. **age restriction**
2. **country restriction**
3. **alcohol**
4. **unpublished** - this is the "is_published" field in the page

Are there others? How do you check for the first three if those restrictions are in effect?

FYI, the current facebook page for which I'm trying to figure out why my user access token works and not my app access token is the "ForestSociety" facebook page.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=ForestSociety&version=v2.0

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, the reason you cannot access a piece of content is intentionally not revealed -

You should be able to access a piece of content via its ID if you received the object ID from another API call (e.g. if you ask for a user's feed and get back a post ID, the post ID should generally be accessible directly), but if you try to access an arbitrary ID and don't have permission to, the reason is intentionally not revealed

Comment: Okay. Fair point. I updated the question. Is there a way to tell which restriction you've hit when you can access the page with one access token (the user access token) and not another (the app access token). Thanks!

Comment: No, you can never tell why you can't see anything.