# Facebook Graph API Business page missing permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a facebook business page and i want to get some posts over the graph api.
I have set everything up (Developer App, Token...).
I get this error when I make an http request:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '492303394120348' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "DxgFcxGEl2Y"
   }
}
```

When i am using the page-id of another facebook page it is working.
What is the problem here. Can someone please help me?

Comment: what token are you using? app token? user token? page token?

Comment: I am using the app tokens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graph API returns 'false' or 'Unsupported get request' accessing public Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843796/graph-api-returns-false-or-unsupported-get-request-accessing-public-facebook)

Answer (score 1):

App Tokens are not a good way to access a Page with the API. If the Page is restricted by age or location, you need a User Token of a user who is able to see the Page, or a Page Token of that Page. You should always consider using a Page Token.