# Salesforce Integration With facebook messanger

Tags: facebook, salesforce, integration, apex

I want to integrate SalesForce with Facebook Messenger. For this I've retrieved access token, app id , app secret. When I hit a HTTP request in developer console to send a message then there is an error.

In the given code it is not accepting messages as parameter throwing error but working without messages.
ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/?translation#sending_text

```
Httprequest req = new httpRequest();
req.setEndPoint('https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/1798927698340/messages?access_token={PUT-ACCESS-TOKEN-HERE}');
String body = '{'+
                '"recipient": {'+
                '"id": "100042977199143"'+
                '},'+
                '"message": {'+
                '"text": "hello, world!"' +
                '}' +
                '}';
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
Http h = new Http();
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

error message :

> 16:55:58:127 USER_DEBUG [16]|DEBUG|{"error":{"message":"Unsupported
>   post request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due
>   to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please
>   read the Graph API documentation at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"error_subcode":33,"fbtrace_id":"AcqDT5M6mGXSOCr4mOd3kDf"}}
>   actual response : success = true

Comment: This means that there are other permissions required. See here [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843796/graph-api-returns-false-or-unsupported-get-request-accessing-public-facebook/6847088#6847088)

Comment: The error message does not seem to match the code you have shown. You are using a specific ID in your code, whereas the error message says you were using the `me` shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises sometimes when we use invalid access token or user access token instead of page access token.